# Does Windows Server 2012/2016 work with different windows versions on client PCs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I am very new to the whole server stuff.
My boss asked me to setup a server for our small company and in the company we have PCs that use different version of windows (such as win7, win8, win10 and 1 or 2 PCs use mac os).  If I setup a server using windows server 2016, will that server be able to communicate with all of our PCs? Such as deploying GPO or files transfer or user account management? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, no problem.  Long answer: for GPO you'll want to become familiar with ADMX files, but the "new" server release should cover "old" operating systems just fine.

As an aside, I will tell you that it is frustrating enough trying to manage GPO with a single client OS, and trying to get consistent GPO policies and settings in place with three Windows OSes might not be too fun.

Edit: Just saw you also mentioned Mac OS.  All bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2016 and 2019 CAN talk to everything but as of 2016 there were some pretty big changes to the GPO structure. Some of the older systems (like if you have any stray Windows XP computers or if you have some weird old Mac running like Pre-Sierra or an old copy machine or something) don't support SMB 3 in any way so you have to turn down the security a couple notches. 2016/19 can make it a bit more difficult.

Pretty much what I do now with everything though is stand up a box with whatever is current on the Core (say 2019) and just put 2016 or 2012 in a VM and use that for your Domain in Hyper-V. Odds are your hardware will be more than enough to handle this and it doesn't use much disk space. Plus management is much easier. Then you also have the ability to stand up a second VM running something older (like a Windows 7 box or something) if need be to handle older applications.

But yes, you can do all that with all those systems you described. You can join MacOS to the domain for user login/home directory but the GPO will not really do anything (MacOS does not have the Registry) so if you want to apply policy then you would need to use a third party utility.